# How can one cite theorems of references?

Tags: citing, theorems

I would like to cite the item (iii) of proposition 3 of a reference. How can I do it? Which ways do you suggest?
This is a question not only about LaTeX, but also about style.
One option I have seen to cite pages of a reference is `\cite[p.~333]{Audet}`. Is there something similar to cite theorems, propositions and so on?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The optional argument of `\cite` & friends is mostly used for page numbers, but references to chapters/sections, paragraphs, verses etc. are not unheard of. Assuming that a declaration like *"Proposition 3.iii"* will refer to a unique location in your source, there's nothing wrong in using `\cite[Proposition~3.iii]{<source>}`. (One may still add the page number, too.)

Note that the [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) package will automatically detect if the optional argument of a citation command contains only numbers and will by default automatically add a page prefix in this case. One may also manually add such a prefix using the `\pno` (for singular) or `\ppno` (for plural) macros. See section 3.12.3 of the manual for details.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite[Proposition~3.iii]{A01}.

Some more text \autocite[Proposition~3.iii on \pno~99]{A01}.

Some more text \autocite[99]{A01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just to mention that `\cite[Proposition~3.iii]{<source>}` will work for almost all `\cite` implementations in LaTeX (whether it be the definition from the LaTeX kernel, `natbib` or some other package). `biblatex` is not required. But `biblatex` has nice features like the automatic detection of page numbers and addition of "p."/"pp." if needed.

Comment: dear moewe by using \cite[Proposition~3.iii]{<source>} i got [?, proposition 3.iii], kindly suggest me the way to get it correct thanks

Comment: By the way, `\cite[something]{source}` apparently doesn't work inside the optional argument for `\begin{theorem}` unless enclosed in `\protect{...}`. So `\begin{theorem}[\protect{\cite[something]{source}}] ... \end{theorem}` works.