# Citing a reference and the equation therein

Tags: citing

I am citing a book in my report. I want to add the equation number to the reference i.e.
I want the reference to appear like [10, eq.8.145].

Thank you.

Comment: `\cite[Eq.~8.145]{foo}`

Comment: Cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36918/15925