# \cite syntax to obtain output: Author (Year, Result)

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

I have a very basic problem. I would like to cite a paper along with a result in it obtaining the following output:

> Joyce (1922, Theorem 24)

Instead, by using standard `\cite[Theorem 24]{Ulysses}`, I get the following:

> (Joyce, 1922, Theorem 24)

Is there a way to get what I am looking for, using the `natbib` package.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. The packages and cite-style you use matter here.

Comment: @jjdb: I do understand your comment. I just did not include the code because I followed a previous question on a rather close topic, which did not contain the code, since the question was rather straightforward and general (so to speak code-independent). Here there is the question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36918/how-can-one-cite-theorems-of-references?rq=1

Comment: Moreover, I am a bit at loss, since the entire code would be `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{natbib} \begin{document} \cite[Theorem 24]{Ulysses} \end{document}`. *(Of course I am assuming the existence of a `Ulysses` entry in a bib file where Joyce is the author, the publication year is 1922 and that's it.)* The problematic issue would be the sintax of `\cite`to get the desired output.

Comment: Well, edit that  into your question. The `.bib` file can be included by the `filecontents` package, see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52412/28751), starting with `\usepackage{filecontents}`, then include your entries in between `\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}` and `\end{filecontents}`. But you could have a look at the `natbib` Documentation, especially p.7 would be helpful for you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page 7 of the [`natbib`-Documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) has an overview of all the citation commands:

> `\citet{jon90}`     ⇒    Jones et al. (1990)
>
> `\citet[chap.~2]{jon90}` ⇒ Jones et al. (1990, chap. 2)
>
> `\citep{jon90}` ⇒ (Jones et al., 1990)
>
> `\citep[chap.~2]{jon90}` ⇒ (Jones et al., 1990, chap. 2)
>
> `\citep[see][]{jon90}` ⇒ (see Jones et al., 1990)
>
> `\citep[see][chap.~2]{jon90}` ⇒ (see Jones et al., 1990, chap. 2)
>
> `\citet*{jon90}` ⇒ Jones, Baker, and Williams (1990)
>
> `\citep*{jon90}` ⇒ (Jones, Baker, and Williams, 1990)

These appear also on the first page of the reference sheet.

Alternatively, you can change the settings via `\setcitestyle{·}`, see later in the manual.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Actually, I did not edit the question nor I check the documentation not out of laziness, but just because I didn't have any access to a computer until now. :)

Comment: @Kolmin Don't worry, you're not expected to jump immediately if someone here says so ;) Btw, in case you don't have internet access, you can also access the documentation by typing `texdoc natbib` in a terminal if you're using TexLive on a UNIX-like system, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367893/where-can-i-find-latex-and-its-package-installation-guide-in-details/367897#367897 Maybe there is also a way for Windows-Latex-Distributions, but I'm not aware of such.

Comment: @Kolmin Also, instead of using `natbib` with `bibtex` I recommend you to consider a change to `biblatex/biber`, which also has `natbib` support with more flexibility, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib for a comparison.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing my attention to `biblatex/biber`: I was not aware of that. I will take a serious look at it.