# Referencing equation number together with citation of the publication

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex

I want to create a citation like:

[15, Eq.(3.27)]

Do you know how can I do it using `\cite`?

Comment: `\cite[Eq.~(3.27)]{sigfridsson}`

Comment: If you are indeed using `biblatex` (you have tagged your question with  both `biblatex` and BibTeX), https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36918/35864 would be a suitable duplicate.

Comment: Can we close this as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36918/35864 or do you need an explicit answer?

Comment: Sorry, @moewe. I didn't see that post.

Comment: Don't worry about that, it's easier to find the answer if you know what it looks like and in this case it is not at all clear what to search for from the beginning. I just wanted to make sure that you agreed this is a duplicate before I voted to close as a duplicate.